# Django Error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10,030'

Tags: python, django

Have this code to import a csv into my Django DB. 
This is my model DB and while saving i got the error. This is the line that created the error

```
 23764,"HUA FU","vessel","DPRK4",-0- ,-0- ,-0- ,"10,030",-0- ,"Panama",-0- ,"Vessel Registration Identification IMO 9020003; Linked To: CHANG AN SHIPPING & TECHNOLOGY."
```

In my DB the column is `vessel_dwt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`

How should i put the column in my DB? as float, or string? This is my importing code.

```
import csv, sys, os

# project_dir = "/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/"
# project_dir = "/Users/Dropbox/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/"
project_dir = "/Users/Dropbox/ofac_project"
sys.path.append(project_dir)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='ofac.settings'

import django
django.setup()

from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Sdn
from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Add
from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Alt
from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Sdn_Comments


file    = 'new_sdn.csv'
file1   = 'new_add.csv'
file2   ='new_alt.csv'
file3   ='new_sdn_comments.csv'

data = csv.reader(open(file),delimiter=",")
for row in data:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Sdn()
        post.number = row[0]
        post.name = row[1]
        post.b_i=row[2]
        post.programe=row[3]
        post.more_info=row[4]
        post.vessel_call_sign=row[5]
        post.vessel_type=row[6]
        post.vessel_dwt=row[7]
        post.tonnage=row[8]
        post.vessel_flag=row[9]
        post.vessel_owner=row[10]
        post.dob_aka=row[11]
        post.save()
```

Before importing i am replace the odd characters:

```
import requests
import csv, os, sys
newstring = "null"
newinteger = str(0)
newstring1= "null"
newstring2= "null"
newstring3= "null"
with open('sdn.csv', 'r') as file1, open('new_sdn.csv', 'w') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(file2, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        replaced7 = row[7].replace('-0-', newinteger)
        row[7] = replaced7           
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code that saves date to DB?

Comment: What kind of number is that supposed to be? Do you mean 10030 or 10.030?

Comment: Consider changing the `"10,030"` literal into the actual number (i.e. remove the surrounding quotes and change the `,` to `.` (if that is supposed to be a decimal place) or simply remove it).

Answer (score 1):

I've removed all the comas from the fields.

I've added this code:

```
replaced7b=row[7].replace(',', '')
        row[7]=replaced7b
        replaced8 = row[8].replace('-0-', newinteger)
        row[8]=replaced8
        replaced8b=row[8].replace(',', '')
        row[8]=replaced8b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this one liner.

`post.vessel_dwt=int(''.join(row[7].split(',')))`